# After writing to a Realm in background thread, the main thread doesn't see updated data

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

1. Clear the database.
2. Make an API call to get the new data.
3. Write the data retrieved from the API into the database in a background thread.
4. Read data from the database on the main thread and render UI.

In step 4 the data should be the latest data, but we're not seeing any data.

```
// remark: all main thread shared a realm object
DBManager.deleteAll()
// call api success, get newdata
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { 
    DBManager.initDBData(<newdata>)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("has data?????", DBManager.getBrands().count)
     }
 }

// when write
func write() {
    let realmBackgroud = try! Realm()
    try! realmBackgroud.write {}
 }
```

Comment: Where have you invoked write function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Realm instances on threads with runloops, such as the main thread, [update to the latest version of the data in the Realm file](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#seeing-changes-from-other-threads) as a result of a notification being posted to their thread's runloop. A time window exists between committing a write transaction on a background thread and when that notification is received by the other thread's runloop, and due to the order that `CFRunLoop` processes its dispatch queue relative to its notification sources, it's not uncommon for a `dispatch_async` to the main queue performed immediately after a write transaction is committed to be serviced before the notification can be delivered.

There are a couple of ways to address this issue:

- Use one of Realm's notification mechanisms, such as collection notifications, to react to the changes you made on the background thread rather than explicitly using `dispatch_async`.
- Explicitly call [`Realm.refresh()`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm7refreshFT_Sb) at the top of the block you dispatch to the main queue to have it bring itself to the latest version, whether or not the thread has had a chance to process the notification that triggers the automatic refresh.